# Sum of Geometric progression?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

A man deposits $200 at the beginning of every year into a bank account at a compund interest rate of 3%per annum. Find out how much he has at the end of 10th year to the nearest dollar?

I honestly don't quite understand the part about "depositing $200 **every year**".

How do you go about solving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first $\$200$ compounds for $10$ years
the next year he deposits another $\$200$ into the account, and that will compound for $9$ more years.

After 10 years he has:

$200(1.03)^{10} + 200(1.03)^9 + \cdots + 200(1.03)$

And how would you sum that up?

Answer (score 3):

At the end of the first year it's going to be $200 \cdot 1.03$; 
at the end of the second year it's going to be $(200 \cdot 1.03 + 200) \cdot 1.03=200 \cdot (1.03+1.03^2)$; 
at the end of the third year we will have $200 \cdot (1.03+1.03^2+1.03^3)$. 
Do you see the pattern?